# Каков наиболее предпочтительный метод поиска всех объектов с компонентом X в Unity?

Tags: unity3d

Это достаточно простой вопрос, на который у меня нет ответа.

Задача, необходимо найти все объекты с компонентом X, которые уже существуют на сцене. То есть, просто кэшировать их в какой то условных момент работы условной фабрики XFactory нельзя, ее просто нет.

Известные мне варианты решения проблемы:

-FindObjectsOfType: этот способ поруган всеми кому было не лень, на нем не останавливаюсь.

-FindGameObjectsWithTag: слышал, что чуть быстрее, однако чтобы не расставлять теги вручную, нужно еще не забыть в компонент X поместить метод с установкой тега. Так же, если компонентов желающих установить свой тег несколько, начнутся проблемы.

-Добавление компонентами самих себя в общее хранилище: это то что пытался сделать я, но оступился на том, что нет ни одного разумного способа убедиться, что в хранилище добавились все компоненты. Можно уповать на Awake, но это плохо скажется на порядке инициализации, да и доверять все порядку Unity мало желания.
Наиболее хорошее, хоть и жутко громоздкое решение вышло, если улучшить хранилище тем, чтобы оно у каждого кто хочет что то из него взять, до кучи просило Action, в который будет при вызываться если появятся новые объекты, которые не успели о себе сообщить.

Все вышеперечисленное так или иначе либо кажется костылем, либо просто неэффективно.

Итак, знает ли кто то лучшие методы решения этой проблемы?

Текущий(он же последний упомянутый) вариант:

```
public class WorldArchive
{
    private Dictionary<Type, List<object>> _archive;
    private Dictionary<Type, List<Action<object>>> _newDataEvents;

    public WorldArchive()
    {
        _archive = new Dictionary<Type, List<object>>();
        _newDataEvents = new Dictionary<Type, List<Action<object>>>();
    }

    public void PutData<T>(T data) 
    {
        if (!_archive.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            _archive[typeof(T)] = new List<object>();
        }
        _archive[typeof(T)].Add(data);

        if(_newDataEvents.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            foreach(Action<object> act in _newDataEvents[typeof(T)])
            {
                act(data);
            }
        }
    }

    public List<T> TakeOutData<T>(Action<T> onNewData) 
    {
        if (!_newDataEvents.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            _newDataEvents[typeof(T)] = new List<Action<object>>();
        }
        _newDataEvents[typeof(T)].Add(onNewData as Action<object>);

        if (!_archive.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            return new List<T>();
        }
        return _archive[typeof(T)] as List<T>;
    }
}
```

Comment: `-FindObjectsOfType: этот способ поруган всеми кому было не лень, на нем не останавливаюсь.` Почему? Тебе нужно единоразово найти объекты, находящиеся на сцене. Создай фабрику, при инстанциировании фабрики кэшируй уже созданные объекты через findobjectsbytype, новые объекты создавай через фабрику. За findobjectsoftype ругают, когда его используют каждый кадр, а не за то, что его просто используют